# Python read and write to files error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a python function that will take different strings and put them into a file such that it will become a python file. It will then run this python file using another python instance. I want this process to time out after a specified amount of time - for example in the case of an infinite loop. Here's the code:

```
# runTimeout.py
input_value = "x = addTwo(1,2)\n"
expected_output = "x == 3"
solution = "def addTwo(a, b):\n\treturn a+b"
timeout = 0.1
# Create the test file by adding (1)submission.solution (2)input_value (3)if (4)expected_output (5): (6) return True (6) return False 
inputFile = solution + "\n" + input_value + "\n" + "if " + expected_output + ":" + "\n" + "\t" + "print True" + "\n" + "print False"
fin = open('inputfile', 'w')
fin.write(inputFile)
fin.close()

command = "python ~/Dropbox/django/inputFile > ~/Dropbox/django/outputFile"

def runTimeout(command, timeout):
    import os, signal, time, commands
    cpid = os.fork()
    if cpid == 0:
        while True:
            commands.getstatusoutput(command)#[1].split('\n')
    else:
        time.sleep(timeout)
        os.kill(cpid, signal.SIGKILL)
    return

runTimeout(command, timeout)
fout = open('outputFile', 'r')
for line in fout:
    print line
fout.close()
```

It correctly generates this inputFile:

```
def addTwo(a, b):
    return a+b
x = addTwo(1,2)

if x == 3:
    print True
print False
```

and this outputFile

```
True
False
```

but when I execute the code with python runTimeout.py, nothing is printed to the console. However, when I read out the file with the last four lines of runTimeout.py using the interpreter, I get the contents of outputFile. What's going on? I can't figure out why the same code works at once place, but not at the other.

I intend to put this into a django function after I get it working independently.

**-- Update --**

Brandon's solution helped, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work consistently from the terminal - sometime, it prints True, sometime it prints nothing.

I wrote this new code instead, which works when it is a separate python file. *Inside a Django function* It fails (500 internal server error) on signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)

```
command = "python ~/Dropbox/django/testcode/inputFile > ~/Dropbox/django/testcode/outputFile"

import signal, subprocess

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception("Timed out!")

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler) #fails here
signal.alarm(timeout) 
results = ""
try:
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    fout = open('outputFile', 'r')
    for line in fout:
        print line
        results += line
    fout.close()
except Exception:
    print "Failure."

signal.alarm(0)

print "results = " + str(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait until your child process exit which makes your code should look like this

```
def runTimeout(command, timeout):
    import os, signal, time, subprocess
    cpid = os.fork()
    if cpid == 0:
        while True:
            subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        time.sleep(timeout)
        os.kill(cpid, signal.SIGKILL)
    os.waitpid(cpid, 0)
    return
```